# jquery dynamically added row is over lapping row c#

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-5

[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]I am adding jquery row dynamically but on adding others after the first one, they are all overlapping(2nd image), please what can be the issue and how can it be solved

Comment: Could you include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: i have added to image for better understanding

Comment: That helps a little, but to help we would need to see some code, so we can make changes on our machines and suggest a fix, without your exact code we're a little lost

Comment: Its possible you have not binded the data into a single HTML ROW `<tr>` , instead of sepearte `<tr>` for each data group. Please provide some code snippet, so that we can get more idea

Comment: This is the script for adding the row:

Answer (score 0):

Until a code snippet is provided, I am not able to provide the exact solution method to employ.

However, utilizing the following example inside your jQuery "add row" function may help:

```
var td1 = '<td> ...something... </td>';
var td2 = '<td> ...something... </td>';
var td3 = '<td> ...something... </td>';


$("tbody").append('<tr>' + td1 + td2 + td3 + '</tr>');
```